# Upgrading umbraco version 4.11.10 to 6.0.0

Tags: content-management-system, version, umbraco, upgrade

I want to upgrade my existing umbraco version project 4.11.10 to 7.5.4, and i decided to upgrade step by step in incremental manner. When upgrading version 4.11.10 to 6.0.0 using nuget package and replacing old dll files with newer one, i am able to run back end and front end side, but on back end, i am not able to view the list of "content" and list of "document types" from my existing project as well as looks like still it displays ui of back end of older version 4, but when i click on "about us", it displays version 6.0.0 as attached in screenshot, please help me to find out the solution, Thanks :)
                          [Check here in attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU4ju.png)
[Check here - Content not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt4CK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from 4.11 to the newest version of 7 should work, HOWEVER, if you're using custom data types, the chances are that some stuff is going to break, as v7 doesn't use UserControls for DataTypes anymore. Some data types can be straight swapped, some not so much. You should be able to see all the DocTypes and content etc though.

When you've swapped the DataTypes out, you may need to reformat the data to match the new DataTypes so you don't lose any data as well. This is something you'd probably have to do either with the API of directly in the database.

I've written some blog posts on upgrading Umbraco, have a read and see if they help:

http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2015/10/upgrading-to-73-part-1-preparation
http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2015/10/upgrading-to-73-part-2-the-upgrade
http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2015/12/upgrading-to-73-part-3-switching-to-razor

http://skrift.io/articles/archive/umbraco-upgrade-strategies/